# Dynamic Fill color in Canvas

Tags: jquery, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working on Canvas object  fill color cylinder dynamically with animation. I have created Cylinder and animation working fine. Right now it was filling color automatically. But what I want is When I enter percentage value in text box cylinder has fill the color.

```
function drawContainer(cx, cy, width, height, degreeAngle) 
{
    ctx.fillStyle = '#E2E2E2';
    ctx.beginPath();        
    ctx.fill();
    defineFillOutline(cx, cy, width, height, degreeAngle);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cx, cy);
    ctx.rotate(degreeAngle * PI / 180);
    ctx.moveTo(-w2, -h2 + h8);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(-w2, -h4, w2, -h4, w2, -h2 + h8);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "royalblue";
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Here is the entire code in JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8b9G8/

Thanks in advance
Maha

Comment: Hi @imtheman now the link is working please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code reads changes in the textbox and fills the cylinder based on a range of 0-100:

Annotated code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/LVW37/

[image][image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
      body{ background-color: ivory; }
      canvas{ border:1px solid red;}
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script>

  $(function() {

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var cw=canvas.width;
    var ch=canvas.height;

    // general variables
    var PI=Math.PI;
    var PI2=PI*2;

    // cylinder related variables
    var cx=cw/2;
    var cy=ch/2;
    var width=65;
    var height=100;
    var w2=width/2;
    var h2=height/2;
    var h4=height/4;
    var h8=height/8;
    var h16=height/16;
    var ytop=-h2+h8;
    var cpYtop=-h2-h16;
    var ybottom=h2-h8;
    var cpYbottom=h2+h16;
    var degreeAngle,rAngle,dx,dy,r,a,xx,yy;
    var bottomFillY=cy+height/2+5;
    var topFillY=cy-height/2+h8
    var fillY=bottomFillY;

    // start the cylinder upright (at 0 degree angle)
    setContainerAngle(0);

    // draw the scene
    draw();

    // draw the scene (background, cylinder, liquid in cylinder)
    function draw(){

        // draw background
        ctx.fillStyle="gray";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);

        // save the context state
        ctx.save();

        // apply transforms
        ctx.translate(cx,cy);
        ctx.rotate(degreeAngle*PI / 180);

        // draw the cylinder clipping region
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(-w2,ytop);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo( -w2,cpYtop, w2,cpYtop, w2,ytop);
        ctx.lineTo(w2,h2-h8);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo( w2,cpYbottom, -w2,cpYbottom, -w2,ybottom);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.clip();

        // draw the fluid clipped inside the container
        ctx.fillStyle='gold';
        ctx.fillRect(-cx,fillY-cy,cw,ch);

        // draw the top-outer lip of the cylinder
        ctx.moveTo(-w2,-h2+h8);        
        ctx.bezierCurveTo( -w2,-h4, w2,-h4, w2,-h2+h8);
        ctx.strokeStyle="royalblue";
        ctx.lineWidth=2;
        ctx.stroke();

        // cleaning up...restore the original context state
        ctx.restore();       
    }

    // change the angle of the cylinder
    function setContainerAngle(degrees){
        degreeAngle=degrees;
        rAngle=degreeAngle*Math.PI/180;
        dx=width/2;
        dy=height/2-height/8;
        r=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
        a=Math.atan2(dy,dx)+Math.PI+rAngle;
        xx=cx+r*Math.cos(a);
        yy=cy+r*Math.sin(a);
    }


    // listen for keyup events on the textbox
    // change the amount of fill in the cylinder accordingly
    $('#filler').keyup(function(){
        var value=parseInt($(this).val());
        if(value<0){value=0;}
        if(value>100){value=100;}
        fillY=bottomFillY-(bottomFillY-topFillY)*value/100;
        draw();
    });


  });   // end $(function(){});

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas><br>
    Percent full (0-100)<input type=text id=filler value=0>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @markE thanks for your valuable response but what exactly I want is  in the textbox if i enter 10% the cylinder has to fill with animation

Comment: Hi @markE thank you so much for your  immense support to me for this task but again :) i need your help or suggest me i need animation when I enter 10% in text box smoothly it has to increase and once again thank you so much for your support Now I have better hope i can submit this

Comment: When the user changes the value in the textbox: (1) cancel any previous animation loop--use cancelAnimationFrame(id), (2) start an animation loop that incrementally changes from the current fill amount to the new value in the textbox. (3) stop the animation when the fill reaches the new value.  The keyup handler in my answer above shows you how to redraw based on a percentage of fill. My previous answer shows how to use an animation loop to change the fillY variable and redraw smoothly.  So between my several answers you have all the tools you need.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Hi i don't want the stroke color I have removed but what I want is top circle should be in different color and currently it was filling like rectangle clip is that possible can the filling will be arc (cylinder) filling

Answer (score 0):

I have got solution for smooth filling in cylinder. In the animation function I have added below code.

```
    if (fillY > (bottomFillY - (bottomFillY - topFillY) * value / 100)){ //112.5
    requestAnimationFrame(animateFill);
    //fillY = bottomFillY - (bottomFillY - topFillY) * value / 100;
    fillY -= 0.50;
}
else{
    requestAnimationFrame(animateFill);
    //fillY = bottomFillY - (bottomFillY - topFillY) * value / 100;
    fillY += 0.50;
}
draw();
```

It was working fine.

Thanks
Maha